# windows phone 8 creating custom static resource

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have a Grid and in that Grid there a several images with some other elements. i want to create a background image as a static resource for each image .I understand that its not impossible so please help me.
for example (this is not the right code, this is just the example of what i want to achieve

```
<style x:key="myimage">
<Setter property="Image" value="images/loading.png"/>
</style>

<image style={staticresource myimage" source={binding someotherimage"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood the problem, but maybe you can try something like this: (this is a example)

XAML

put this in PhoneApplicationPage :

```
 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <my:BinaryToImageSourceConverter x:Key="BinaryToImageSourceConverter1" />
  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Put this in your Grid:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource BinaryToImageSourceConverter1}, ConverterParameter=Image, TargetNullValue='/Image/no-foto-60.png'}"  Stretch="None" />
```

you must implement the class BinaryToImageSourceConverter: IValueConverter

```
namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    public class BinaryToImageSourceConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
        {
            if (value != null && value is byte[]) 
            {
                try
                {
                    var bytes = value as byte[];
                    var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                    var image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                    return image;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            } 
            return null; 
        }      
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) 
        { 
            throw new NotImplementedException(); 
        } 
    }
}
```